# i want to show date of previous day on my title

Tags: gnuplot

I have my line as follows on gnuplot

```
set title "Auto Requests - ".strftime("%b %d %Y", time(0))
```

however, this will only show the date I am generating the report but I want to show the date of the previous day "1 day ago" like the linux function.

Anyone has an idea how to adjust this line?

Comment: `time(-1)`, `time(-86400)` ? What does this have to do with `bash` or `perl`?

Comment: @mob it means that people who watch the [tag:bash] tag see the question and identify a solution based on shell tools, since gnuplot doesn't support this natively.

Comment: noted. will not do that no more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, the `time` function in gnuplot only returns the current time. You can pass it a format string directly, by the way (no need to combine it with `strftime` as you have done).

One option would be to use the external `date` utility:

```
system("date -d yesterday +'%b %d %Y'")
```

This will return the string from yesterday's date, in the desired format.